# How to encrypt a .tar file using pgp encryption in Java

Tags: java, encryption, tar, pgp

I trying to encrypt a .tar using .pgp encryption technique , i have key value(which is again not a file)which i have to use to encrypt the .tar file. The key value is a string (i.e. keyVal="xxxxx").I am taking the reference from the below URL which is there in the github, and is referenced by many users.

https://github.com/matthewmccullough/encryption-jvm-bootcamp/blob/master/bc-pgp/src/main/java/com/ambientideas/cryptography/KeyBasedFileProcessorUtil.java

This this example i want to encrypt the .tar file which i have in the location

../myTarLocation  in my code

```
public static void encryptFile(
    OutputStream    out,
    String          fileName,
    PGPPublicKey    encKey,
    boolean         armor,
    boolean         withIntegrityCheck)
    throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException
{    
    if (armor)
    {
        out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
    }
    
    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream       bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        

        PGPCompressedDataGenerator  comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(
                                                                PGPCompressedData.ZIP);
                                                                
        PGPUtil.writeFileToLiteralData(comData.open(bOut), PGPLiteralData.BINARY, new File(fileName));
        
        comData.close();
        
        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator   cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom(), "BC");
            
        cPk.addMethod(encKey);
        
        byte[]                bytes = bOut.toByteArray();
        
        OutputStream    cOut = cPk.open(out, bytes.length);

        cOut.write(bytes);
        
        cOut.close();

        out.close();
    }
    catch (PGPException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
        if (e.getUnderlyingException() != null)
        {
            e.getUnderlyingException().printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But i can't understand where i shall use the keyVal which i have , and how i will encrypt the **.tar file into a .tar.pgp file.** .Can anyone please help me.

Comment: You either do symmetric encryption, which uses a key value, OR you do asymmetric encryption which uses the recipient's public key.  If you're being given a public key you don't need a symmetric key also.

Comment: @JimGarrison No, that's exactly the wrong way around. You either do symmetric encryption or you do hybrid encryption which is asymmetric encryption or key establishment and symmetric encryption. PGP generally uses hybrid encryption (unless a password is used instead of a public key).

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes i have a key which can be treated as a password I don’t have a file

Comment: Bouncy Castle provides a fine example that encrypts (or decrypts) a file using a passphrase: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/PBEFileProcessor.java